# Где взять полный список всех значений detailed_status при language = ru в pyowm

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyowm

Я делаю gui приложение с погодой в основе работы которого у меня лежит pyowm. В приложении есть картинки (облока с грозой, со снегом, солнце и прочее) и я хочу чтобы в зависимости от значения detailed_status они менялись на соответсвующие. Но для реализации мне нужен весь список значений detailed_status чтобы для каждого я подобрал соответсвующую картинку. Но я просто не знаю где его найти. На openweathermap нет, в документации pyowm вроде как тоже
[image: Скриншот приложения]